# MongoDb filter by total query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a sample like this.

Sample:

My document row like this.

```
_id                          counts                              createdAt
58adc57a1f84e37c19df0ccb    [600, 100, 400, 500, 700, 200, 300] 2017-02-07T13:23:38.320Z    
. other document rows
. other document rows
. other document rows
...
```

I want to query

> totalPrice between 20 and 30

and

> salaryTime between "2016-01-26","2018-02-02"

How can I write a query?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
[
    {"$addFields": { "total_counts": { "$sum": "$counts" } } },
    {"$match": {  
        "total_counts": { "$gt": 2700 , "$lt": 3000 },
        "createdAt": { "$gt": ISODate('2016-01-26'), "$lt": ISODate('2018-02-02') }
        } }
]
)
```